# Alfresco form validation during submit

Tags: forms, validation, alfresco

I want to add a form validation using form engine.This link shows alfresco form field validation example http://blog.mwrobel.eu/field-validation-alfresco-share-form/ . But I want to know is how to validate form during submit. Can you show me some code sample??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

accidentally I'm mwrobel.eu ;)

Are you really sure you NEED to validate something on submit? Because of forms engine & surf engine you would have to dig deep in alfresco sources to do that. The preferable way of extending Share is to do it using JS.

Keep in mind that, what I've told in my blog article, isn't only way to validate forms with JS. You can for instance also override control&forms .ftl's and embed your own validating JS code there. That's surely easier than going deep inside alfresco share java classes.

[Here you can find list of .ftls you can override](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms)